# Protecting my database files

Tags: .net, sql-server, security

I have a Windows .net application using SQL Server 2005 Express as database, which is used on a server with multiple clients. The users insert, view and update data via the application.

For this, I have to put the .mdf files in a folder on the server. Is there any other way?

Now in this case, anybody can take those .mdf files and open them in their SQL Server & view the database objects such as tables,views and procedures.

Therefore, I want to protect my .mdf files with high-level or maximum security and ensure that :

1. no one can even copy those files from the server.
2. if the files are copied then they themselves should not open,
3. if opened then they should ask for passwords

So, please guide me how to implement this security?

Also, I want to know when someone copies the database files, then whether the user, logins, roles are also copied or not?

Comment: Just secure your server. No-one will be able to copy the files unless you share them, or the person has physical access to the server.

Comment: For point 1: secure your server - no one needs access to those directories on the server from their workstation for this app to work! I don't think there's anything you can do for no. 2 and 3 - you cannot make a MDF file "not open" - nor can you assign a password for the opening process....

Comment: Ok since I can't read, voted to delete my answer, need more information now. Since it's a Windows Application, how is the application connecting to the database? Does each application have it's own database on the client machine, or are you connecting to the database remotely via Web Service's or TCP etc?

Comment: Sounds like he/she is just connecting to the mdf file using a network path.

Comment: @sqlchild, Are you using a Database Server or just a Database File?

Comment: thanks a lot to everybody, for their answers.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Dear Sir,  i have installed sql server on one system(server) and the other three systems are connected through LAN to the server. i will run the application on the three client machines.all the machines have windows xp. now, i have installed the application on the clients and it connects to the server using tcp.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Dear Sir, whats the difference between database server & database file. according to me when we create a database in SQL Server, then SQL Server generates an .mdf file for it. and all the database objects (tables, procedures) are added into that file only.so what would be the difference if a use mdf file or sql server, in both the cases the insertions and updations done would be updated in the .mdf file finally. the benefit of using sql server would be that: logins and user permissions can be used . would there by any other benefits also?

Comment: @Phil, Dear Sir, i have installed sql server on one system(server) and the other three systems are connected through LAN to the server. i will run the application on the three client machines.all the machines have windows xp. now, i have installed the application on the clients and it connects to the server using tcp

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Sir, currently my application is a simple application, a windows form which has text boxes for accepting user data, & a delete button for deleting data from the sql database. i am using connection string to connect to the sql database. i have made an alias of my sql instance , A-9, the alias is A-9-1. now i used Client Network Utility on the client machines to add those aliases.and then the application connects to the sql.

Comment: @Phil, dear sir, my application is installed on the client and server machines & the database is only on the server machine which is having sql server on it. the client machines are accessing the database present on the server machine and inserting and updating data into it via the .net application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have looked into this as well.  In reality with SQL Express, someone can simply stop the service and copy the database files without issue.  These can then be ported over to another instance.

Windows security and other products whether you use group policy or some other after market tools that can lock down the file system are your best bets for file system security.

I beleive SQL does offer exactly what you are looking for and that is TDE encryption.  Sadly this is only available in Enterprise edition and how many folks does that actually help out.

You could also encrypt specific columns directly in your database.  If you have a certain set of tables that you are worried about this is probably the best option offered with Express at the current time.

Check out this article by Dave Pinal:  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/

I have tried it and it does work well to protect your sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in SQL Server you can enable encryption then if somebody gets your .mdf but does not have valid credential should not be able to see the data in it.

Comment: To me it doesn't sound like he/she is using SQL Server, but just a standalone mdf.

Comment: This is incorrect.  You can encrypt your connection with Express.  This offers no protection over the MDF

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(v=sql.100).aspx <-- Is this what you're referring to Davide? *just googled it* think it's only apart of enterprise. I think the OP needs to explain his architecture a little for everyone to better help him.

Comment: Yes I was talking about this, I meant Full Database Encryption which covers you in case somebody steals your .mdf files :) Did not know it was available only in the Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about actually using a database server instead of just a database file.  Using a server will allow you to lock down who has access to the database and make it so that only your application (through a username and password) can access it.

This would mean using SQL Server 2005 Express (I think it's limited on the number of connections) or MySql Server.

If that really isn't an option then:

1) You would have to secure the folder, but this might mean your application cannot access the mdf as well.

2 & 3) Both can be tricky.  I think that there are some third party tools that can encrypt a file for you, but that will mean you have to change your application and how it accesses the file.

4) You could make a custom service that watches the directory, but you will not be able to tell if the internal aspects of the mdf are copied or not.  Generally, if the mdf is copies you are probably safe assuming that the roles, logins and users were copied with it.